# How to add redmonnt.dll using AddMonitor() under Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, 64-bit, port

I'm trying to register redmon monitor on Windows 7 64 bit. Here is an example of code I use:

```
MONITOR_INFO_2 info;
info.pName = "RedmonMonitor";
info.pEnvironment = "Windows x64";
info.pDLLName = "redmonnt.dll";
SetPrivilege("SeLoadDriverPrivilege",TRUE);
AddMonitor(NULL, 2, (LPBYTE)&info);
```

It works perfectly on WinXP with "Windows NT x86" environment specified. On Windows 7 AddMonitor() returns FALSE, GetLastError() returns 0.

At the moment of calling redmonnt.dll already copied to "C:\Windows\system32" (also it automatically appears at "C:\Windows\SysWOW64").

Also I experimented with Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection() as suggested [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/ca34c65c-7270-439c-b19b-8f421278a4c6), didn't help.

I tried "Windows NT x86" and "Windows x64" environment values.

Using thoughts from [here](http://borntoidentify.blogspot.com/2010/09/configuring-virtual-printer-using.html) regarding privileges tried to launch program as administrator, didn't help.

redmonnt.dll taken from redmon17 package from the official site.
SetPrivilege() taken from msdn examples with small modifications.

Would be grateful for any ideas on how to make this work.
Thank you.

Comment: Wrong pinvoke declarations, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of redmonnt.dll you use? Is it [64-bit DLL](http://www.winimage.com/misc/redmon/) or 32-bit version from [the official site](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/)? The DLL will be loaded by spoolsv.exe which is 64-bit application on the 64-bit operation system. So you have to use 64-bit version of the DLL.